# How can I implement text recognition on an iOS app?

Tags: ios, iphone, image-processing, image-recognition, text-recognition

I'm new to iOS development and I'm trying to make an app that, using the iPhone's camera, recognizes a string of numbers and converts them to text.

Is there a module for iOS development that I can easily incorporate into my app? Or is there a generic module that I can possibly try to port iOS?

Of course, a free module is better.

Thanks in advance :)

**Edit:** To remove the hold moderators have put on this question, I've put the following requirements:

1. The module will take an image or an area of an image as input and recognize the text on it.
2. The module must be compatible with one of the iOS development languages.
3. The module must be able to work without an internet connection (a local engine as opposed to one that sends requests to a server)

Comment: It is Image to Text ?

Comment: Yessir! It's converting text in an image into actual, manipulatable text.

Comment: To the moderators that put the question on hold, thank you for your comments. Although I'd be happy to describe the problem in more detail so as to solicit more technical and specific answers, having such specifications would require me to posses technical knowledge I do not yet have. I am merely asking for a starting point, which shouldn't be as polarizing a topic as you deem it to be. I kindly submit that you remove the hold on the question so that I can get the quality answers from the S/O community. If you can suggest specific edits to the question, I'd be happy to oblige.

Comment: Actually, the link you posted about editing my answer raises some good points. This question doesn't ask people what their favorite library to perform the task is. It asks _if_ there is such a library. There either is or there isn't. There can be multiple possible answers but the answerer's opinion doesn't really change whether or not it is a good answer. If the library works then good, we have more options. If not, then that is a problem with the answerer, not the question. Please take this into consideration.